# Django Formset Edit View

Tags: python, django, forms, formset

Recently  I started to learn Python Django myself. I am working with a django formset. Some one please help me with edit view of this formset. Here is the create view.

```py
def create(request):

    context = {}
    InvoiceFormset = modelformset_factory(Invoice, form=InvoiceForm)
    form = OrderForm(request.POST or None)
    formset = InvoiceFormset(request.POST or None, queryset=Invoice.objects.none(), prefix='invoice')
    if request.method == "POST":
        if form.is_valid() and formset.is_valid():
            try:
                with transaction.atomic():
                    order = form.save(commit=False)
                    order.save()
                    print("form saved")

                    for invoice in formset:
                        data = invoice.save(commit=False)
                        print(data)
                        data.invoice_id = order
                        data.save()
                        print("formset saved")

            except IntegrityError:
                print("Error Encountered")

            return redirect('/', messages.success(request, 'Order was successfully created.', 'alert-success'))

    context['formset'] = formset
    context['form'] = form
    return render(request, 'new.html', context)
```

Comment: What is your problem? Please update question.

Comment: This is the create view function of my form. I am using a form to save Customer details and a form set to save order details. This create form is working perfectly. I would like to add a edit view of this code. formset section is not showing the saved data on edit view. Please help. Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`UpdateView` [Django-Docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.UpdateView) to create a view for editing this model.

*Example: (`Order` model)*

**views.py**

```py
class OrderUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = Order
    template_name_suffix = '_update_form'
    fields = '__all__'
```

**template**

Create a template in location `<app_name>/order_update_form.html` (*Replace `<app_name>`* with name of your app)

```html
<form method="post">  
    {% csrf_token %}  
    {{ form.as_p }}  
    <input type="submit" value="Save">  
</form>
```